# How to set property of variable

Tags: c#

this is my function which gets all projects placed in database.

```
 public bool getUserProjects(ref List<erpAssets>userProjects)
        {

            string arguments = "{\"sessionId\":\"" + m_LoggedInUser.sessionId + "\"," +
                                 "\"assetType\":\"" + PROJECT_ASSET_TYPE_NAME + "\"" +
                                "}";
            string response = UrlParser(METHOD_GET_ASSETS, MODULE_ADMINISTRATION, arguments); //calling the function urlParse to get the response from that page

            erpAPIResponse basicResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<erpAPIResponse>(response);

            if (basicResponse.success.Equals("yes"))
            {
                try
                {

                    erpAssets[] Projects = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<erpAssets[]>(basicResponse.arguments);
                    userProjects.AddRange(Projects);

                }
                catch (Exception e)
                { 

                }

            }
            else return false;

            return true; // sending the response back to client            
        }
```

My erpAsset class is as follows:

```
 class erpAssets
    {
        public string assetId { get; set; }
        public string assetSerialNo { get; set; }
        public string serialNo { get; set; }

        public string assetDescription { get; set; }
        public string assetType { get; set; }
        public string parentId { get; set; }
        public string assetIsTrakable { get; set; }

        public bool isTrackable { get; set; }
        public bool isMovable { get; set; }


        public string assetInheritsRegion { get; set; }

        public string inheritsRegion { get; set; }

        public string assetModel { get; set; }

        public string model { get; set; }

        public erpPoint[] assetRegion { get; set; }

    }
```

and my erpPoint class is as follows:

```
class erpPoint
    {

        public double X { get; set; }
        public double Y { get; set; }
    }
```

Now issue i am facing is this when assetRegion is null then i get following exception

Error converting value "" to type 'erp.erpPoint[]'.

scenario1 which is working fine:
 {
        "assetId": "43711",
        "assetSerialNo": "Sector43",
        "assetDescription": "",
        "assetVersion": "",
        "assetIsMovable": "f",
        "assetType": "Project",
        "assetModel": "Project",
        "parentId": "32537",
        "assetIsTrackable": "f",
        "assetInheritsRegion": "f",
        "assetRegion": [
            {
                "X": -122.69103924537,
                "Y": 49.105749366835
            },
            {
                "X": -122.69103924537,
                "Y": 49.119046702041
            },
            {
                "X": -122.68010753619,
                "Y": 49.119046702041
            },
            {
                "X": -122.68010753619,
                "Y": 49.105749366835
            }
        ]
    }

this is working fine.

Scenario2:

{
        "assetId": "64374",
        "assetSerialNo": "FeedLot",
        "assetDescription": "",
        "assetVersion": "",
        "assetIsMovable": "t",
        "assetType": "Project",
        "assetModel": "Project",
        "parentId": "64374",
        "assetIsTrackable": "t",
        "assetInheritsRegion": "f",
        "assetRegion": ""
    }

this is where i am getting exception. assetregion is null and now i am getting exception in setting its values

Comment: `""` doesn't look like a valid array to me. It seems an exception is the logical result.

Comment: @KendallFrey has a point, `""` is not `null`, it is an empty string, so the exception while converting it to a `erp.erpPoint[]` is expected

Comment: so if i get "" then how to ignoe exception?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two choices:

Use

```
{ get; set; }
```

and you can't specify a body.

Or you must declare a body **for both the getter and the setter**.

Also do note `double` is not nullable. Use `double?` instead.

```
private double? x;

public double? X
{
    get { return this.x; }

    set
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            this.x = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Warning `StackOverFlowException`

Comment: Well spotted. Body of the null check should set `x`, not `X`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a custom setter, you must also provide a custom getter. Usually that means you need to create the backing field yourself.

```
class a
{
    private double x;

    public double X
    {
        get 
        {
            return this.x;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != null) // warning, see below
            {
                this.x = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, you also have the issue that a `double`, like all value types<sup>*</sup>, is not nullable, this whole method is probably not necessary at all. If you want to ensure that `X` is never set to a null value, just declare it as a `double` and you won't have to worry about that. This would be sufficient:

```
class a
{
    public double X { get; set; }
}
```

<sup>* except for `Nullable<T>`</sup>

Comment: sir i am getting exception that "" value cant be assigned thats why i have made null check

Comment: @MuneemHabib Where are you getting that error? It can't in any of the code you've shown here. If you include the full use case, we might be able to point out the real issue or provide an alternative solution. However, that's probably beyond the scope of this question as it stands now, and you probably will be better off opening a new question to resolve that issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the verbose syntax:

```
private double? x;

public double? X
{
 get { return x; }
 set { 
        if (value != null){
           x = value;
        }
    }
}
```

**Update**

Someone correctly pointed out `double` can't be null, changing the type to a nullable.

Comment: double cannot be null

Answer (score 0):

You can *either* use auto-properties or properties backed by a field. You cannot mix. In your case this would mean

```
public double? DifferentPorpName
{
    get {return this.X;}
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

as far as set goes i would change it to the following, it's more declarative to me:

```
set
{                
    double x = value;
    if (value != null) x = value;
    else x = this.X;

    this.X = x;
}
```

your `get` needs to be declared properly or omitted entirely

and i forgot to ask you, how can you pass null to a property of double? you will definately get an error on runtime if you try it.

Ooops, others have already noted it :)

Comment: Declaring an unnecessary variable doesn't make it declarative. And you definitely *won't* get an error at runtime, but at compile time. Also, there's a stack overflow waiting to happen.

Comment: as I said, more declarative to ME :) it's obvious visual studio won't let you assign null to a double. it will allow the comparison operation though and if used incorrectly after a parse or convert you'll get an error on runtime